# Pre populate form element using struts2 error with validation

Tags: java, jsp, validation, struts2, struts2-jquery

I have a form with few text boxes. The text box values are initialized to default values using **`customerSer`** action.

I can change the default values and submit the form using **`customer`** action. Both the action belongs to the same class with different methods used for each action.

This works fine as long as i do not have any validation for the form. Once form validation is applied, the first action does not work and gives error and looks for result type `input`.

I need to do struts2 validation for the form elements. Is there any other approch can be taken for form population of data or validation?

**Struts.xml**

```
<action name="customerSer"
            class="net.test.struts2.action.TestAction" method="initialize">
            <result name="none">Customer.jsp</result>
</action>        

<action name="customer"
            class="net.test.struts2.action.TestAction">
            <result name="success">SuccessCustomer.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">Customer.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**TestAction.java**

```
package net.viralpatel.struts2.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

    public class TestAction extends ActionSupport {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7154564763591606533L;
        private String name;
        private Integer age;
        private String email;
        private String telephone;

        public String execute() {
            return SUCCESS;
        }

        public String initialize() {
            System.out.println("Aditya");
            this.name="Aditya";
            this.age=28;
            return NONE;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(Integer age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getTelephone() {
            return telephone;
        }

        public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
            this.telephone = telephone;
        }
    }
```

**TestAction-Validation.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
<validators>
    <field name="name">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message key="errors.required" />
        </field-validator>
    </field>
    <field name="age">
        <field-validator type="required">
            <message key="errors.required" />
        </field-validator>
        <field-validator type="int">
            <param name="min">1</param>
            <param name="max">100</param>
            <message key="errors.range"/>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
    <field name="email">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message key="errors.required" />
        </field-validator>
        <field-validator type="email">
            <message key="errors.invalid" />
        </field-validator>
    </field>
    <field name="telephone">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message key="errors.required" />
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

**Customer.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Customer Form - Struts2 Demo | ViralPatel.net</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Customer Form</h2>

<s:form action="customer.html" method="post" validate="true">
    <s:textfield name="name" key="name" size="20" />
    <s:textfield name="age" key="age" size="20" />
    <s:textfield name="email" key="email" size="20" />
    <s:textfield name="telephone" key="telephone" size="20" />
    <s:submit key="label.add.customer" align="center" />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Link to pre populate data customer.jsp**

```
<body>
    <h2>Howdy, <s:property value="username" />...!</h2>
    <s:a href="customerSer.html">Add Customer</s:a>
</body>
```

Comment: Change validation file name to `TestAction-customer-validation.xml`.

Comment: Its working. Can you please tell me what is the difference it makes after this modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your validation xml file is named like this `TestAction-validation.xml` that means that validation process will happen for all actions in `TestAction` class. So your validation is configured per action class, in order to configure it per action name as it is given in the `struts.xml` file you need to name your validation file like that `TestAction-customer-validation.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use @SkipValidation annotation, on the method you don't want, the validation to apply.

[Reference](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/validation-annotation.html)

```
class MyAction extends ActionSupport{

 @SkipValidation
 public String view(){       //validation will NOT be applied here
   ...
 }

 public String save(){           //validation will be applied here
  ...
 }

}
```